# proper way of inserting data with id as auto-increment in mysqli

Tags: mysql

can someone please verify the proper way of inserting data using MYSQLI?

i need to insert comment data into the table with ID set as auto-increment. do i just leave the values for id as *blank* ?

```
$db = dbConnect();
$query = "INSERT INTO comments values ('', '$comment')";
$db->query($query);
```

Comment: Your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proper way would be either omit value, or assign NULL to it.
While empty string which is used in your example, is not a valid value and in strict mode it will issue a warning.

```
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (NULL, 'comment')
INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES ('comment')
```

are all valid.

Answer (score 1):

For an auto-increment column, you can omit it from the column list, and it will generate a new auto-increment value. You do this as @YourCommonSense showed, by specifying all columns *except* for the auto-increment column:

```
INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES ('comment')
```

For what it's worth, MySQL does the same thing if you specify 0 or `NULL` or `DEFAULT` for the auto-increment column.

Below is an example test:

```
mysql> select version();
+---------------+
| version()     |
+---------------+
| 5.6.13-56-log |
+---------------+

mysql> select @@sql_mode;
+--------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                 |
+--------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------------------------+

mysql> insert into comments values (0, 'comment1');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into comments values (null, 'comment2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into comments values (default, 'comment3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from comments;
+----+----------+
| id | comment  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | comment1 |
|  2 | comment2 |
|  3 | comment3 |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, leave it blank and MySQL gives it a value.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (data_column_name) VALUES ('$comment')";
```

Comment: real_escape_string does not prevent injections, mind you. **Prepared statement** have to be used instead.

Comment: I just removed the text.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, your statement is too strict. The real_escape_string method, when used correctly, is just as effective as parameters at preventing SQL injection. I do agree that parameters are simpler and make my code more clear. I prefer using parameters.

Comment: @BillKarwin just read this function's name. There is **not a single word** like "injection", "protection" or such. The purpose of this function is definite and certain. And it has nothing to do with whatever injections. And this function **should not** be recommended as a protection measure. Just because such a recommendation IS the very source of the most injections in the world. Especially when given to unsuspicious PHP user, who still believe that this function's purpose is to "sanitize" whatever "dangerous characters" in "user input"

Comment: @YourCommonSense, if you're assuming PHP developers use the function improperly, then prepared statements with parameters have the same weakness. Neither do parameters mention "injection" or "protection" in their name. Your arguments are specious.

Comment: @BillKarwin this latter statement of yours is plainly wrong. Prepared statements with parameters DON'T have the same weakness. Even if misused, prepared statement still allows no injection. **This Is The Point.**

Comment: And yes, you are right - injection protection is not a primary task for prepared statements. They do it as just a side effect.

Comment: Just like real_escape_string does it as a side effect also? Documentation tells us unsuspicipus users to use it to prevent injection. Haven't heard any complaints about it untill now, so, what's wrong with it?

Comment: real_escape_string DOESN'T. This documentation page you are talking about is a bloody shame. Note that a page for the newest version of this function contain no such ambiguous or misleading statement.

Comment: I have yet to see any arguments on why this function is is dangerous. When you initially wrote your comment, I thought I had ooverlooked something. Now, I think you're overreacting.

Comment: If you think that users shouldn't use real_escape_string because they might try to escape table names with it: That's like saying that I can't use C or C++ because I might write outside allocated memory or even I that I can't drive a car because it's possible to crash. Living by rules like that is impossible, as almost anything can be abused and used for something not intende.

Comment: Please **don't** get me wrong. Nowhere did I say real_escape_string shouldn't be used. In your answer you made a connection between this function and injection, which I objected. The rest is your speculation, nowhere connected to what I said.

Comment: Using libraries like PDO of course makes things less error prone. The documentation on PHP SQL-security, http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php, recommends using Prep. statements if available, but that you should use real_escape_string if it's not. The designers of real_escape_string tells us that this is a function that may be used against SQL-injection, just like PDO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39400/discussion-between-atle-and-your-common-sense)

Comment: 1. I don't need no manual pages as a proof for my words, because I have understanding of my own. 2. This statement you're talking about is plainly wrong. 3. If you don't want to understand it yourself but your only intention to show me that I am wrong - don't waste your time.

Comment: I asked you if you could tell why real_escape_string is bad. You did not answer to that. So for now, I have to stick to the documentation.

Comment: Nowhere did I say real_escape_string is bad. You don't listen to me but talking rather to yourself. I am not responsible for your speculations. By the way, I've corrected that manual page you're talking about, it's pending for the build. Check it back in some time for the clarification. Thanks for pointing out.