# Inserting autoincrement id mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

First of all: I searched in google and stackoverflow for: insert auto increment id in mysql, [found this on SO but it was not helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406292/proper-way-of-inserting-data-with-id-as-auto-increment-in-mysqli). Everything else I found was for mysqli->insert_id;
If I missed a point in searching for a solution i'd apprichiate a correct link in the comments.

I'm trying to "translate" old mysql_*-functions to mysqli_* functions.

Assuming my old query was:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bugtracker` 
        (`id`, `date`, `workerid`, `currURL`, `prevURL`, `bugTitle`, `bugDesc`) VALUES 
        (NULL, '".time()."', '$worker', '$clean[currURL]', '$clean[prevURL]', '$clean[bugTitle]', '$clean[bugDesc]');");
```

For understanding:
(`$clean[currURL]` = `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['currURL']);`)

New it has to be something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `bugtracker` (`id`, `date`, `workerid`, `currURL`, `prevURL`, `bugTitle`, `bugDesc`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = $mysqlicon->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param('iiissss', 'NULL??', time(), $worker, $_POST['currURL'], $_POST['prevURL'], $_POST['bugTitle'], $_POST['bugDesc']);

$statement->execute();
$statement->close();
```

Question: I didn't try to run my query in anyway because i'm curious how I should insert the previous "NULL" to my autoincrement id in mysqli. Should I just ignore and leave it empty? Just don´t show it in `$query` and `bind_param`?

Table structure is in this order:
`id`(int11), `date`(int11), `workerid`(int11), `currURL`(varchar), `prevURL`(varchar), `bugTitle`(varchar), `bugDesc`(text)

Comment: So an answer telling you to omit the column was "not helpful" while an answer telling you to omit the column worked like a charm. A typical logic of a PHP user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not specify this column (id) in your statement.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Stupid question, "easy" answer.  Thanks for your help, now the work starts.