# How to execute 2 SQL queries one after the other using mysqli_multi_query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, fgetcsv, mysqli-multi-query

I was trying insert values simultaneously into MySQL database using mysqli_multi_query but it's not executing and going to if part showing alert message stating Record Insertion Failed.

Below is my PHP code with query

```
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $sql_tableone =  "INSERT into inverterlog (`id`,`timestamp`,`irradiance`,`ambienttemp`,`photovoltaictemp`,`pv1voltage`,`pv2voltage`,`pv3voltage`,`pv1current`,`pv2current`,`pv3current`,`pv1power`,`pv2power`,`pv3power`,`pv1energy`,`pv2energy`,`pv3energy`,`gridvoltagegv1`,`gridvoltagegv2`,`gridvoltagegv3`,`gridcurrentgc1`,`gridcurrentgc2`,`gridcurrentgc3`,`gridpowergp1`,`gridpowergp2`,`gridpowergp3`,`sumofapparentpower`,`gridpowertotal`,`gridenergyge1`,`gridenergyge2`,`gridenergyge3`,`socounter`,`gridcurrentdcgc1`,`gridcurrentdcgc2`,`gridcurrentdcgc3`,`gridresidualcurrent`,`gridfrequencymean`,`dcbusupper`,`dcbuslower`,`temppower`,`tempaux`,`tempctrl`,`temppower1`,`temppowerboost`,`apparentpowerap1`,`apparentpowerap2`,`apparentpowerap3`,`sovalue`,`reactivepowerrp1`,`reactivepowerrp2`,`reactivepowerrp3`,`opmode`,`latestevent`,`pla`,`reactivepowermode`,`overexcitedunderexcited`,`reactivepowerabs`,`inverter`)
                                                          values('','$newDate','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]','$emapData[9]','$emapData[10]','$emapData[11]','$emapData[12]','$emapData[13]','$emapData[14]','$emapData[15]','$emapData[16]','$emapData[17]','$emapData[18]','$emapData[19]','$emapData[20]','$emapData[21]','$emapData[22]','$emapData[23]','$emapData[24]','$emapData[25]','$emapData[26]','$emapData[27]','$emapData[28]','$emapData[29]','$emapData[30]','$emapData[31]','$emapData[32]','$emapData[33]','$emapData[34]','$emapData[35]','$emapData[36]','$emapData[37]','$emapData[38]','$emapData[39]','$emapData[40]','$emapData[41]','$emapData[42]','$emapData[43]','$emapData[44]','$emapData[45]','$emapData[46]','$emapData[47]','$emapData[48]','$emapData[49]','$emapData[50]','$emapData[51]','$emapData[52]','$emapData[53]','$emapData[54]','$emapData[55]','$inverter')";
    $sql_tabletwo = "INSERT into data (`id`,`timestamp`,`gridpowertotal`,`inverter`) values ('','$newDate','$emapData[26]','$inverter')";
    $sql= $sql_tableone.";".$sql_tabletwo;
    $result = mysqli_multi_query( $con,$sql);
    if (! $result ) {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"multi query Record Insertion Failed.\");
            </script>";
    }
    fclose($file);
}
//throws a message if data successfully imported to mysql database from excel file
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
    window.location = \"four.php\"
/</script>";
//close of connection
mysqli_close($con); 
}
}
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: Use `mysqli_error()` to print out the error message

Comment: @jens...application is for general purpouse....included mysqli_error()..still showing nothing...

Comment: Than echo out the query and try it in mysql console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `id` column is auto-incremented in the tables, then omit the column (and the empty value) from your query.  Alternatively, you can use `NULL` (not quoted) if you are going to mention the column in your query.

Many, many people struggle to find the errors with their `mysqli_multi_query()` code block because it is not set up to properly output affected rows and errors.

I recommend having a look at a general purpose code block that will help to isolate troublesome queries, and [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715889/strict-standards-mysqli-next-result-error-with-mysqli-multi-query/22469722#22469722).

It also looks like you are while-looping `mysqli_multi_query()`'s two queries. For efficiency, I recommend building up the full array of queries, finishing the loop, then calling `mysqli_multi_query()` only once.

p.s.  Do any of your insert values have quotes in them?  Prepared statements would help with that issue.  Use the code block from my link and check the error message.

UPDATE: Here is my spoon-fed answer (Of course, I didn't actually test it before posting):

```
// I assume $newdate is not user declared and considered safe.
// I am using NULL for your auto-incremented primary key `id`.
// If you want to be assured that each pair has an identical `id`, perhaps use LAST_INSERT_ID() on second query of pair.

// establish variables for future use
$inverterlog_sql="INSERT INTO `inverterlog` (`id`,`timestamp`,`irradiance`,`ambienttemp`,`photovoltaictemp`,`pv1voltage`,`pv2voltage`,`pv3voltage`,`pv1current`,`pv2current`,`pv3current`,`pv1power`,`pv2power`,`pv3power`,`pv1energy`,`pv2energy`,`pv3energy`,`gridvoltagegv1`,`gridvoltagegv2`,`gridvoltagegv3`,`gridcurrentgc1`,`gridcurrentgc2`,`gridcurrentgc3`,`gridpowergp1`,`gridpowergp2`,`gridpowergp3`,`sumofapparentpower`,`gridpowertotal`,`gridenergyge1`,`gridenergyge2`,`gridenergyge3`,`socounter`,`gridcurrentdcgc1`,`gridcurrentdcgc2`,`gridcurrentdcgc3`,`gridresidualcurrent`,`gridfrequencymean`,`dcbusupper`,`dcbuslower`,`temppower`,`tempaux`,`tempctrl`,`temppower1`,`temppowerboost`,`apparentpowerap1`,`apparentpowerap2`,`apparentpowerap3`,`sovalue`,`reactivepowerrp1`,`reactivepowerrp2`,`reactivepowerrp3`,`opmode`,`latestevent`,`pla`,`reactivepowermode`,`overexcitedunderexcited`,`reactivepowerabs`,`inverter`) VALUES (NULL,$newdate";
$data_sql="INSERT INTO `data` (`id`,`timestamp`,`gridpowertotal`,`inverter`) VALUES (NULL,'$newDate'";
$tally=0;
$x=0;

// build all queries
while(($emapData=fgetcsv($file,10000,","))!==false){
    ++$x;
    $sql[$x]=$inverterlog_sql;  // start first query of pair
    for($i=1; $i<56; ++$i){
        $sql[$x].=",'".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$emapData[$i])."'";
    }
    $sql[$x].=",'".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$inverter)."');";  // end first query of pair
    $sql[$x].="$data_sql,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$emapData[26])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$inverter)."')";  // whole second query of pair
    fclose($file);
}

// run all queries
if(mysqli_multi_query($con,implode(';',$sql)){
    do{
        $tally+=mysqli_affected_rows($con);
    } while(mysqli_more_results($con) && mysqli_next_result($con));
}

// assess the outcome
if($error_mess=mysqli_error($con)){
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Syntax Error: $error_mess\");</script>";
}elseif($tally!=$x*2){  // I don't expect this to be true for your case
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Logic Error: Only $tally row",($tally!=1?"s":"")," inserted\");</script>";
}else{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\"); window.location = \"four.php\"/</script>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: @Pradeep You tell me.  Take my advice about the INSERTed `id` column & value.  Replace your query code block with the suggested code block from my linked answer -- it will tell you if/when you have failures.  If you can't fix the failure yourself, edit your question with the error message, then ping me and I'll have a look.  If my answer fixes your issue, please award it the green tick.

Comment: Here is a reference about the `NULL` auto-incremented column value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406292/proper-way-of-inserting-data-with-id-as-auto-increment-in-mysqli

Comment: @mickmackusa.....when  am executing mysqli_multi_query..and print its value im getting boolean 1...what it means ...??? ac to my knowledge its executing successfully...Then why its going to if-loop part...

Comment: @Pradeep I have a sneaking suspicion that you are not taking my advice and that you haven't implemented my suggested code block... because if you did, it WILL tell you how many rows are affected and if/where there is an error.

Comment: @Pradeep I have done a complete code rewrite for you.  Now I am hoping for the selected answer and an upvote.   If this still doesn't sort out your issue, leave me a comment that explains the error/problem and I'll try to help some more.

Comment: @mickmackusa...ive implemented your code block ...Thanks for the advice..,used null in place of id in my query and also used mysqli_error..its working f9 now....thanks a lot buddy..